# Processing a list 1..n elements at a time without explicit recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I find myself often using a pattern where I transform a list with a function that consumes 1..n elements from the list and produces some result out of those. E.g.

```
process :: [a] -> [b]
process [] = []
process xs = first : rest
    where (first, xs') = consume xs
          rest         = process xs'
```

Where the `consume` function consumes a variable number of items from the list and returns a result and the remaining list items. Can I use some standard higher order function here instead of the explicit recursion?

Comment: That would be a nice combinator. I couldn't find it through hoogle. My search term was `([a] -> (b,[a])) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you need is similar to `unfoldr`. If you would bring your `consume` into the following form:

```
consume' :: [a] -> Maybe (b,[a])
```

Where `consume'` returns `Nothing` in case of an empty list, or `Just ...` otherwise. This is a small wrapper, that captures that pattern:

```
wrap :: ([a] -> (b,[a])) -> [a] -> Maybe (b,[a])
wrap f [] = Nothing
wrap f xs = Just $ f xs
```

Then you can use `consume` with `unfoldr` with the original definition of `consume :: [a] -> (b,[a])` like this:

```
unfoldr (wrap consume)
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, that either `consume` has this type ending in a `Maybe` or you redefine `consume` and use `wrap` too, but it got garbled (doesn't type check).  You either need a `join . wrap consume` or be more explicit that `consume :: [a] -> (b,[a])`.  As it is, you get a `Maybe (Maybe (b,[a])` being passed to `unfoldr`.

Comment: @TomMD Fixed the ambiguity with `consume`. I expected `consume` to be the original `consume` in the last example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unfoldr` with some wrapper around `consume`, but I wish there where a higher order function for exactly the pattern you have.  I have suggested adding one to `Data.List`.  I too use it a lot.

Comment: Totally agree. This would be a very useful function for `Data.List`.